# Construction of Python ndarray which uses strings as indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am most certainly a newbie when it comes to python. About 1 week into learning it and realize there are a lot of tools here I should be using. One of them is numpy.darray. However i am having difficuly applying it to my problem.

I have the following array data structure: string -> value. That is I want something like

**a["string1"] = 4.5**.

I then need to associate this array to an object where **"attr" -> a["string1"]**, so in the end I have the following

**b["attr"] -> (a["string1"] -> 4.5)**

This way if I were to make a call like the following

**b["attr"]["string1"]** it will return 4.5

In other words a 2D numpy array where I can use strings instead of integers to access my array. Or perhaps there is another better way to do this in python?

Comment: You can use `dict`.

Comment: Best way is to use a `dict`, where data is accessed by keys and not indices, which are usually strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for dictionaries. Please refer to [Data Structures: 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Dictionaries allow you to not only store numeric values but also other data structures as lists, arrays, data frames or **dictionaries itself**.

Your example:

```
a = {"string1": 4.5}

a["string1"]
> 4.5

b = {"att": a}

b["attr"]["string1"]
> 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710321) states, you most likely want a dictionary. However, just for your information, there exist NumPy-like structures that can be indexed by strings, namely those offered by [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) (for more than two dimensions there is [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/)). For example, using a `Series` object:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
print(s)
# abc    1
# def    2
# ghi    3
# dtype: int64
print(s['abc'])
# 1
print(s[['def', 'ghi']])
# def    2
# ghi    3
# dtype: int64
```